# Hadoop 1.2.1 - "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf" during mapreduce compilation

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to learn how to use Hadoop 1.2.1.

I've created my first cluster, but can't compile mapreduce example in java (Eclipse 2021-03)

Here is my source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;    

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;

public class WordCount {

    public static class WordCountMapper extends MapReduceBase
            implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

            private Text word = new Text();

            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                            throws IOException {
                    String line = value.toString();
                    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
                    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                            output.collect(word, new IntWritable(1));
                    }
            }
    }

    public static class WordCountReducer extends MapReduceBase
                    implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

            public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
                            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                            throws IOException {

                    int total = 0;
                    while (values.hasNext()) {
                            total += values.next().get();
                    }
                    output.collect(key,  new IntWritable(total));
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
            conf.setJobName("Word Count");

            conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            conf.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
            conf.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

            conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
            conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

            JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

I'm not an author of this code, just found example somewhere in network.

```
While trying to run application, it shows me this error:

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf
        at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

What can be the reason, that JobConf class can't be found?
In referenced libraries I have hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar and other from hadoop directory.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? :)

Best regards!

Comment: you need to add some libraries in your project. Make an executable Jar in Eclipse. Check this error `NoClassDefFoundError:` in Java and you can find many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue,
Tried this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure hadoop-common dependency is present

Answer (score -1):

in the main you setting the conifiguration for the job.
but you havent imported. So try to import the following:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).